# readline error upon installing a new ruby version using rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, ruby-2.3

Trying to install **ruby-2.3.1** using `rbenv install 2.3.1`. 
Following is the error trace from the above command that failed.

```
BUILD FAILED (Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09 using ruby-build 20160602)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20161024151611.24040
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20161024151611.24040.log

Last 10 log lines:
# define rl_username_completion_function username_completion_function
^
readline.c:1780:37: note: in expansion of macro 'rl_username_completion_function'
rl_username_completion_function);
^
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory /tmp/ruby-build.20161024151611.24040/ruby-2.3.1/ext/readline' 
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory/tmp/ruby-build.20161024151611.24040/ruby-2.3.1'

sudo yum install readline-devel

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Package readline-devel-6.2-9.14.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Can you try this: https://gist.github.com/juno/1330165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tested in (Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09 using ruby-build 20160913-13-g8ef0c34)
>
> > Run the following commands in terminal

```html
$ sudo yum install -y git gcc openssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel
$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
$ type rbenv
$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
$ rbenv install 2.3.1
```

> ```
> $ rbenv install 2.3.1
> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
> perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
>     LANGUAGE = (unset),
>     LC_ALL = (unset),
>     LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
>     LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
>     are supported and installed on your system.
> perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
> Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
> -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
> Installing ruby-2.3.1...
> Installed ruby-2.3.1 to /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with rvm: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

`rvm install ruby-2.3.1`